# How to get latitude and longitude of center of google map

Tags: asp.net, javascript, google-maps

Please tell me how can i raise event just after user change his position in google map using dragging map and get the latitude and longitude of center of google map and the miles its showing from center. i have got lots of pages on google related to it.. but not able to solve this.. please give me solution (i am using asp.net and javascript)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
GEvent.addListener(map, "moveend", function() {
  var center = map.getCenter();
});
```

Comment: can u please tell me how can i find out how many miles currently its showing from center point (in radius)

Comment: i got it we can do it with map.getZoom(); but please tell me how to convert it to mils

Answer (score 1):

You can add moveend() or dragend() event ([reference](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/reference.html)) and call getCenter() method to get the new map center
Further resources to search for the links and code related to google map api is : 
http://groups.google.com/group/google-maps-api

Comment: can u please tell me how can i find out how many miles currently its showing from center point (in radius)