# How to find the current location(longitude and latitude) using Google Map?

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geolocation

I just want to ask how can I get the current latitude and longitude using Google Map? Because I am creating a Map Tool for adjusting maps in database. If there is a given latitude and longitude simply display the map. I have no problem with that. But if the longitude and latitude is NULL or 0. How can I get the exact latitude and longitude?

I have this PHP:

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= $companies_count; $i++) :
$company = $companies[$i];
$company_id = $company['company_id'];
$file_id = $addresses_file[$i]['company_id']; //file information from textfile
$file_latitude = $addresses_file[$i]['new_lat'];
$file_longitude = $addresses_file[$i]['new_long'];
foreach($addresses_file as $y){
  if($company_id == $y['company_id']){
    $lat = $y['new_lat'];
    $long = $y['new_long'];
  }else{
    $lat = $additionals[$company_id]['geo_lat'];
      $long = $additionals[$company_id]['geo_long'];
      if($lat == 0 || $lat == NULL){
              //set lat to current position
      }
      if($long == 0 || $long == NULL){
              //set long to current position
      }
    }
}
endfor;
```

...and my JavaScript:

```
var maps = {},
geocoder = null;
function showAddress(address, i) {
  if (geocoder) {
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address' : address },
      function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
          var id = i;
          var center = results[0].geometry.location;
          document.getElementById("lat_" + id).innerHTML = center.lat().toFixed(5);
          document.getElementById("long_" + id).innerHTML = center.lng().toFixed(5);
          maps[id].mapObj.setCenter(center);
          maps[id].marker.setPosition(center);
          $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("tr[rel='" + id + "']").offset().top
          }, 1000);
        }else{
          alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
        }
      }
    );
  }
}

function fn_initialize() {
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  var hh_map = {
    init: function(lat, lon, z_lvl, label, id){
      var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon);
      var mapOptions = {
        zoom: z_lvl,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        streetViewControl: false,
        overviewMapControl: false,
        mapTypeControl: false,
        panControl: false,
        zoomControlOptions: {
          style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL,
          position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_BOTTOM
        },
        center: latlng,
      };                                        
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas_" + id), mapOptions);
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: map.getCenter(),
        title: label,
        draggable: true
      });
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function(e) { // update lat_{id}/long_{id}
        var center = marker.getPosition();
        document.getElementById("lat_" + id).innerHTML = center.lat().toFixed(5);
        document.getElementById("long_" + id).innerHTML = center.lng().toFixed(5);
      });
      maps[id] = {'mapObj' : map, 'marker' : marker};
    }
  };
$('.map_canvas').each(function(){
    if ($(this).data('lat') && $(this).data('long')) {
      hh_map.init($(this).data('lat'), $(this).data('long'), 16, $(this).data('label'), $(this).data('company_id'));
    }
  })
}

function loadScript() {
  var script = document.createElement("script");
  script.type = "text/javascript";
  script.src = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&callback=fn_initialize";
  document.body.appendChild(script);
}

window.onload = loadScript;
$(document).ready(function(){
  //update address
  $('.save-button').each(function(index, elm){
    $(elm).click(function(){
      var id = $(this).attr("id"),
      val_lat = $('#lat_' + id).html(),
      val_long = $('#long_' + id).html();
      if (val_lat.length > 0 && val_long.length > 0) {
        var x = confirm("Are you sure you want to update this?");
        if(x == true){
          $('<form action="" method="POST">' +
          '<input type="hidden" name="company_id" value="' + id + '">' +
          '<input type="hidden" name="new_lat" value="' + val_lat + '">' +
          '<input type="hidden" name="new_long" value="' + val_long + '">' +
          '</form>').submit();
        }else{
          return false;
        }
      } else {
        alert('New locations are empty!');
      }
      return false;
    })
  })
  $('.revert-button').each(function(index, elm){ //revert address
    $(elm).click(function(){
      var id = $(this).attr("id"),
      val_lat = $('#lat_' + id).html(),
      val_long = $('#long_' + id).html();
      if (val_lat.length > 0 && val_long.length > 0) {
        var x = confirm("Are you sure you want to revert this?");
        if(x == true){
          $('<form action="" method="POST">' +
          '<input type="hidden" name="company_id" value="' + id + '">' +
          '<input type="hidden" name="new_lat" value="' + val_lat + '">' +
          '<input type="hidden" name="new_long" value="' + val_long + '">' +
          '</form>').submit();
        }else{
          return false;
        }
      } else {
        alert('New locations are empty!');
      }
      return false;
    })
  })
})
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get latitude and longitude of center of google map](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2221361/how-to-get-latitude-and-longitude-of-center-of-google-map)

Comment: OK thanks I will check that

Answer (score 5):

With JavaScript, you can use:

```
var center = map.getCenter();
alert(center.lat() + ', ' + center.lng());
```

The top answer shown in the linked duplicate question is for Google Maps V2.

Comment: @RochelleCanale That will give you the center of map. If you want to get the user's current location, you'll need to look into using something like Geo IP. Unfortunately, it won't always be accurate.

Comment: @RochelleCanale Depends what you want? Are you looking for the current location of the user or are you looking for the center of the map.

Comment: @Jerielle And are you looking for the current location of the user or are you looking for the center of the map?

Comment: I need to get the current location of the user who view the map tool. Is it possible?

Comment: Have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16380544/get-the-longitude-and-latitude-as-users-machine-in-php